# Aeotect smart HUB Third party API for integration with our software platform?

Tags: samsung-smartthings, nb-iot

I was finding a Smart Hub which supports the large variety of sensors of different companies so after doing some research I found an Aeotect hub that can meet this requirement. Now Aeotect hub has smartThing SDK integrated into it so it can be controlled with the smartThing platform now what I want is to control the Aeotect hub with my own software platform(website/App). So I have done more research and found out API documentation of the smartThing platform but I have the following problems related to it:

1. They have told to generate a bearer Token I don't know how to generate it?
2. Is this API is free of cost or do I have to do a partnership with them?
3. And also want to know the use of developer workspace.

And I also want to know is there any other way by which I can control this Aeotect hub with my software platform.